# requirejs + angularjs code structure split in different files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm using requirejs and Angular and I'm trying to create an application structure that allows me to split every controller/services/directives etc in different files. This is the structure I'd like to achieve:

```
src/
components/
    Navigation/
        index.js
        module.js
        NavigationController.js
        NavigationService.js
```

In module.js I'd like to do something like this:

```
define(['angular', './NavigationService', './NavigationController'], function (angular, NavigationService, NavigationController) {
    'use strict';
    return angular.module('Myapp.Navigation', [])
        .controller('NavigationController', NavigationController)
        .service('NavigationService', NavigationService)
});
```

And having the controller/service definition defined in a separated js file.

The issue is that I don't know how to define these files. I've tried with this syntax:

```
//NavigationService.js
define( function() {

            this.doNavigation = function () {
                console.log('I am navigating');
            }
    });
```

but doesn't look to be working.
Have you ever seen this kind of structure using requirejs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
//NavigationService.js
define([], function() {
    NavigationController.$inject = ['$scope', '$q', 'myOwnService', 'etc'];
    function NavigationController($scope, $q, myOwnService, etc) {
        ...
    }
    return NavigationController;
});
```

You may also be interested in [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need `requirejs` in case of single application. Top level hierarchy in angular is application. All applications have its set of modules and angular should have all it's sources from the start, so you have no need to load it using requirejs.

Instead, I'd recommend you to use `grunt` with `concat` plugin. It will assemble you application's pieces all together and you will have single file for each application.

Then, when you have one file for each application, you can load it with requirejs, it have sense, but not loading modules.

Also check [angular code style](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), it has a lot of suggestions of how to write in right way.

**UPD:** About your problem: if you have set of modules that are common for your applications (I mean you have a lot of them) then you probably interested in using `require.js` with `angular.js`. In this case [read and follow recommendations](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/) from this article. Otherwise, you don't really need `require.js`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I have to use requirejs for other reasons (the project is more complex, it uses libraries and this is just a small part of it). I'm using grunt-contrib-requirejs

Comment: @gabric read article above, it has few main thoughts I found not obvious: requirejs and angularjs has separate injection managers; you should use manual bootstraping for angular, if you use requirejs.